# Trying to add a header around an anchor with javascript prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I'm trying to place headers around a couple of anchors with Prototype. But it doesn't work? Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

```
            function placeheader(item, i)
            {
                item.insert({
                    //This doesnt work:  
                    before: "<h3>",
                    after: "</h3>"

                    //This works:           
                    //top: "test3",
                    //bottom: "test4"
                }); 
            }               
            $$('div.subresult a').each(placeheader);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot use the insert() method with partial tags, try this:

```
function placeheader(item) {
    var header = $(document.createElement("h3"));
    item.up().insertBefore(header, item);
    item.remove();
    header.appendChild(item);
}
$$("div.subresult a").each(placeheader);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `wrap()` method

```
$$('div.subresult a').each(function(item){
    var header = new Element('h3');
    item.wrap(header);

});
```

http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/wrap/

Comment: Thanks this also works fine! :-) Never knew about the wrap method